# Laravel Homestead could not connect to server 127.0.0.1

Tags: laravel-5, vagrant, homestead

I have installed laravel homestead and vagrant. After vagrant up my local site started work.

My migrations worked well and i could connect to DB with PhpStorm ( http://joxi.ru/a2X45M1S1x3Vw2 )

my .env file contains the same code as written in doc

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=54320
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

But when I try to register new user I got an error

> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused Is
>   the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP
>   connections on port 54320?

( http://joxi.ru/nAynW7asYOD39r )

How it possible when migrations run well but connection refused?

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot says that Laravel is having trouble connecting to `192.168.10.10`, which isn't the same as `127.0.0.1`. Check that the correct `DB_HOST` is set in your `.env` file.

In case the config from the `.env` file isn't being used, also check the `config/database.php` file and verify the settings there too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `.env -> DB_PORT`
for `pgsql` use `DB_PORT=5432`

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue, and what worked for me was to change my DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 to ip: "192.168.56.56"(the same id that is on my Homestead.yaml file).